# iterate through an array (and a bit more)

Tags: matlab, iteration

I am looking to find out how I iterate through the following matrix i have created from an image:

```
Img = imread('tinycircle.png');
Img = Img(:,:,1);
Img = double(Img);
[x,y] = size(Img);
I = ones(x,y);
```

I want to iterate through each pixel Img and determine each pixel's distance from the shape (in this case a circle) in `I = ones(x,y);`

I know i can use something like:

```
R = pdist2(Img,I);
```

but just need a little help iterating through each pixel of the image.

Comment: You are looking for something called [Distance Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform).
It is quite easy to implement once you understand the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the image processing toolbox, you can use binarize the image, e.g.

```
bw = Img > 0;
```

then use the command

```
I = bwdist(bw);
```

Comment: Can you please use an actual image processing toolbox function in your example?

Comment: @Superbest I'm not sure what you mean, `bwdist` is an image processing toolbox function: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html